# Log Missing Column in Destination Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the code below which allows me to update the existing spreadsheet (much like an matrix lookup). And what I am doing right now is to include a error log which will be updated in another sheet, this includes Missing data in Column A in Destination Spreadsheet and Missing Column in Destination Spreadsheet. I have worked with Missing data in Column A, my problem was the Missing Column, cause instead of the column name (found in the row 1) the result shows the column index:

code:

```
function updateShadowSKU() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('179PCrIWe1mvbbzOi9ySEHxzBlFaXpCB2i0wHlYVE2vg').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var destRange = dest.getDataRange();
  var destValues = destRange.getValues();
  var destHeaders = destValues[0];
  var destIds = destValues.map(e => e[0]);
  var values = source.getDataRange().getValues().map(e => e.filter((f, i) => !i || i > 10));
  var colMap = values[0].map(e => destHeaders.indexOf(e));
  Logger.log(colMap);
  values = values.map((e, i, arr) => e.map((f, j) => [e[0], colMap[j], f, values[0][j], i, j])).flat().filter(e => e[0] && e[1] && e[2] && e[3] && e[4] && e[5]);
  Logger.log(values);

  // Initialize an array to store log entries
  var logEntries = [];

  // Check for missing SKUs
  values.forEach(function(e) {
    if (!destIds.includes(e[0])) {
      logEntries.push(["Missing SKU", e[0], e[3]]);
    }
  });

  // Check for missing column headers
colMap.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if (e == -1) {
    var index = destHeaders.indexOf(values[0][i]);
    colMap[i] = index;
    if (index == -1) {
      logEntries.push(["Missing column header", values[0][e], ""]);
    }
  }
});

  if (!values.length) {
    logEntries.push(["No changes to make", "", ""]);
  } else {
    values = values.map(e => [destIds.indexOf(e[0]), e[1], e[2]]);
    Logger.log(values.length + ' changes to make');
    Logger.log(values);
    values.forEach(function(e) {
      try {
        destValues[e[0]][e[1]] = e[2];
      } catch (err) {}
    });
    destRange.setValues(destValues);
  }

  // Write log entries to the 'Shadow Log' sheet in the destination spreadsheet
  if (logEntries.length > 0) {
    var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('179PCrIWe1mvbbzOi9ySEHxzBlFaXpCB2i0wHlYVE2vg').getSheetByName("Shadow Log");
    if (logSheet == null) {
      logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('179PCrIWe1mvbbzOi9ySEHxzBlFaXpCB2i0wHlYVE2vg').insertSheet("Shadow Log");
    }
    logSheet.clear();
    logSheet.getRange(1, 1, logEntries.length, 3).setValues(logEntries);
  }
}
```

the code block for getting the missing data in Column A destination spreadsheet works fine, but what I am having a hard time is getting the column name. The code block below shows only  the column index instead of the comlumn title/header:

```
// Check for missing column headers
colMap.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if (e == -1) {
    var index = destHeaders.indexOf(values[0][i]);
    colMap[i] = index;
    if (index == -1) {
      logEntries.push(["Missing column header", values[0][e], ""]);
    }
  }
});
```

sample sheets:
source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zGqiYocUmSBRDPKRqI3iI3nIf7w3b9C7ykT-QffBROA/edit#gid=0

destination: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PjOvhscblzPxaBnJi1Q5oB6iCAt9_emljUR6vlAfIA0/edit#gid=0

example:

source data:

```
|   SKU      |   walmart1   |   amazon 2   |   ebay1   |
|============|==============|==============|===========|
| SKUitem1   |    SKUwm1    |              |  SKUebay1 |
| SKUitem2   |              |              | SKUitem5  |
| SKUitem3   |   SKUwmi1    |              |           |
```

destination:

```
|   items    | **walmart2** | **amazon 1** |   ebay1   |
|============|==============|==============|===========|
| SKUitem1   |    SKUwm1    |              |  SKUebay1 |
|**SKUitem5**|              |              |           |
| SKUitem3   |              |              |           |
```

desired result:

in this scenario the 'Shadow Log' sheet should result into

```
|   Missing SKU    |   SKUitem2    |
|  Missing Column  |   walmart1    |
```

missing SKU - cause there were an update from the source but unable to find it in the destination

missing column - cause there were an update on that column but unable to find that column

you will also see that there is a mismatch column amazon 2 --> amazon 1, but you will see nothing in the desired results, it is because there's no new data to be updated.

I hope this clears things out, please don't hesitate to ask me

Comment: May I confirm if what you want as an output is the error and then the column header? For example, `Missing Column Header - walmart shadow 2`?

Comment: Better yet, would you please edit your spreadsheets to show the entries that should appear in the "Shadow Log" of each spreadsheet.

Comment: sorry, I  have updated the post into the showing the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check and Fix the Index when Accessing Desired Data

I noticed that when you tried to access the data from `values`, you used `[e]` as the index which will lead to an `undefined` value since `[e]` will always be `-1` in your case and there is no `-1` index in an arrays.

Also, when using the `forEach` method, the first variable (e in your case) will be the value  to be processed while the second variable will be the index value (i in your case). Hence, you should use `[i]` when accessing data using loops.

With all that, I added a `sourceCol` variable to store all wanted column headers from the source.

[image]

You may change the range if you should add more columns. I changed `values[0][e]` to `sourceCol[0][i]` to access the wanted column header.

The new code should look like this: (I added comments for further guidance)

```
function updateShadowSKU() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Destination Sheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var destRange = dest.getDataRange();
  var destValues = destRange.getValues();
  var destHeaders = destValues[0];
  var destIds = destValues.map(e => e[0]);
  var values = source.getDataRange().getValues().map(e => e.filter((f, i) => !i || i > 10));

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //added sourceCol variable to specifically get the array of all Column Headers from the Source
  var sourceCol = source.getDataRange().getValues().map(e => e.filter((f, i) => i >= 3 && i <= 17));
  var colMap = sourceCol[0].map(e => destHeaders.indexOf(e));
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  values = values.map((e, i, arr) => e.map((f, j) => [e[0], colMap[j], f, values[0][j], i, j])).flat().filter(e => e[0] && e[1] && e[2] && e[3] && e[4] && e[5]);


  // Initialize an array to store log entries
  var logEntries = [];

  // Check for missing SKUs
  values.forEach(function (e) {
    if (!destIds.includes(e[0])) {
      logEntries.push(["Missing SKU", e[0], e[3]]);
    }
  });

  // Check for missing column headers
  colMap.forEach(function (e, i) {
    if (e == -1) {
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //change values[0][e] to sourceCol[0][i]
      logEntries.push(["Missing column header", sourceCol[0][i], ""]);
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
    }
  });

  if (!values.length) {
    logEntries.push(["No changes to make", "", ""]);
  } else {
    values = values.map(e => [destIds.indexOf(e[0]), e[1], e[2]]);
    Logger.log(values.length + ' changes to make');
    Logger.log(values);
    values.forEach(function (e) {
      try {
        destValues[e[0]][e[1]] = e[2];
      } catch (err) { }
    });
    destRange.setValues(destValues);
  }
    // Write log entries to the 'Shadow Log' sheet in the destination spreadsheet
    // Added an else statement to clear the 'Shadow Log` when the log is empty.
  var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Destination Sheet ID').getSheetByName("Shadow Log");
  if (logEntries.length > 0) {
    if (logSheet == null) {
      logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Destination Sheet ID').insertSheet("Shadow Log");
    }
    logSheet.clear();
    logSheet.getRange(1, 1, logEntries.length, 3).setValues(logEntries);
  }
  else {
    logSheet.clear();
  }
    }
```

### Output

In testing the code, I deleted 5 column headers (as seen below):

[image]

When I ran the code with the modification, I got the following output:

[image]

### References

- [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Accessing Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: Please feel free to ask/comment about the answer since it is based on assumptions since you have not included a sample/desired output.

Comment: Hello @PatrickdC, yup, that's the kind of result that I want to achieve, but upon testing the result, the result in 'Shadow Log' is different, like when I deleted the 'ebay shadow 3' in the destination, it resulted into 'groupon shadow 2'. I have edited the post, and I hope things will be cleared, I have also added sample sheets

Comment: I have updated the answer and added some adjustments to the code. I added a new variable so that it will not interfere with the `values` variable.